# MySQL Workbench * could not be fetched

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, privileges

I set up a MySQL Server on a Ubuntu machine.

I added a user A with only access to one Database 'B'.

If I log in with it in MySQL Workbench, it shows me:

- Tables could not be fetched
- Views could not be fetched
- Stored procedures could not be fetched
- Functionscould not be fetched

The fun thing is that under "Tables could not be fetched" all tables of the DB are shown. The query SHOW TABLES; also gives the correct result.

If I log in with the root user or a user with all privileges on *.* it displays everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, I attempted to dump my database (as a backup) and it generated an error message that was more specific.

The error message indicated that one of my views was referencing a table that I had previously renamed. After updating the view to use the table's new name, the messages, such as "Tables could not be fetched", "Views could not be fetched", and so forth, disappeared.

Basically, when MySQL Workbench displays "could not be fetched" errors, attempt to dump the database, in which the errors are displayed, in order to get a more helpful error message, and then try to correct that problem.